# JPA/Hibernate with Dynamic Object Model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with the number of column is variable (depend of customer), 
so I looking for a way to mapping this table with a java object using JPA/Hibernate or other

I can not use POJO because it's limited to a stable table so I'd like to use java object like this

```
class MyObject {
int id;
Map<String, Object> fields = new  Map<String, Object>();

public void setId(int id) { 
    this.id = id; 
}

public void setField(String key, Object value) { 
    fields.put(key, value);
}
```

}

The table for storing MyObject :

```
TABLE MYTABLE (
ID INTEGER,
FIELD1 VARCHAR, 
FIELD2 DATE, 
FIELD3 INTEGER
)


MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setId(id);
myObject.setField("FIELD1" , "hello world");
myObject.setField("FIELD2" , new Date());
myObject.setField("FIELD3" , 21)

Action to save myObject in db;
```

And of course the possibility to query

Comment: If you are not aware of your schema. You should go for Nosql. Eg. Mongo

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am constraint to use relationale database  (sqlserver for now)

Comment: See dynamic models http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels

Comment: Thanks Alan, it's looks interesting. In your link v(3.3) it said : The following features are currently considered experimental and may change in the near future.
In v5 no this notice, I hope hibernate will keep and maintains this fonctionality.

Unfortunatly the documentation is pretty lite. But in the idea, this is match with my goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate supports what they refer to as Dynamic Models. See further the following link which notes:

> Persistent entities do not necessarily have to be represented as
>   POJO/JavaBean classes. Hibernate also supports dynamic models (using
>   Maps of Maps at runtime). With this approach, you do not write
>   persistent classes, only mapping files.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#dynamic-model

Previous versions of the Hibernate docs give some more detail. See:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels

There's an example here that seems (from a quick skim) to allow for combining normal POJO with dynamic fields.

https://www.infoq.com/articles/hibernate-custom-fields

Comment: thanks again Alan, I have found this link also : http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/domain-models-and-metadata-hibernate/