# Dynamic properties in Spring Boot Data with Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to store dynamic properties (definition can change at runtime) for multiple other entities.

My basic data model:

- "property" table with columns (id, property_name, entity_name, property_type)
- "property_value" table (id, entity_id, property_id, value) // for now value is a String

Now i create a materialized view (using native SQL) for each entity.

For Example:

- in the "property" table there are entries (1, "test", "Book", "String"), (2, "testNum", "Book", "Number")
- the view looks like

```
select pv."entity_id" as "id",
cast(max(case when p."name" = 'test' then pv.value else null end) as Varchar(20)) as "test",
cast(max(case when p."name" = 'testNum' then pv.value else null end) as Integer) as "test",
from property p
    left join property_value pv on pv.property_id = p.id
    where p.entity_name = 'Book'
    group by pv.entity_id
```

When i have a JPA Entity like Book

```
@Entity
class Book {
  Long id;
  String name;
  @Transient
  Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

I want the spring boot JPARepository/Hibernate to join the properties and put those into the Map.
The sql could look like

```
select b.id, b.name, b_p.test, b_p.testNum
from book b
left join book_properties b_p on b.id = b_p.id
```

Then the Map should have entries for "test" and "testNum" with the appropriate column value.

I there any way i can tell Hibernate to do that without losing all the other benefits.
I really don't want to write native queries for paging and sorting and filtering...

The sorting should also work on the properties.

If only there was a JPA/Hibernate Annotation like

```
@JoinAllColumns(table = "book_properties")
Map<String, Object> properties;
```

which always joins the given table (native sql table name) and puts all column values into the map.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39768075/1915448

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @g00glen00b It seems like the answer suggests manipulating the hibernate mapping and using hibernate auto update to modify the DB schema which seems dangerous. I only want to ever modify the view and make hibernate use that.